# next.js state object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```js
    const [ state , setState ] = React.useState({
        input_type: '',
        elements: []
    })

    const createOption = () => {
        let newElements = state.elements
        newElements.push({
            type: "option",
            value: "",
            id: state.elements.filter(e => e.type === 'option').length
        })

        setState({ elements: newElements})
    }


    return( <div> <input type='text' onChange={ createOption } /> </div> )
```

`cannot read property push of undefined` I have no idea why is `state.elements` is undefined. I wanted to push a element into the `elements` array inside the `state`

Comment: Please show `state` before declare `newElements`

Answer (score 0):

don't use **reference** copy or **shallow** copy to create newElements.

you can use a simple approach in javascript called spread operator to create and modify an object easily.

so you can change your createOption in this way:

```
const createOption = () => {
    setState( prevState => ({
         ...prevState, elements: {
            ...prevState.elements,
            {
                // create your new object here
                type: "option",
                value: "",
                id: prevState.elements.filter(e => e.type === 'option').length
            }
            
        }))
```

Comment: I assumed that your `elements` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix something this way:

```
const createOption = () => {
setState( prevState => ({ ...prevState, 
                     elements: [ ...prevState.elements,
                         {
                             type: "option",
                             value: "",
                             id: prevState.elements?.filter(e => e.type === 'option').length || 0
                         }
        
                     ])
        )
```